# How create authentication in Symfony 3.2

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I don't know, how create authentication in Symfony 3.2

I want load Security Users from the Database. I use msyql in my project.

My security.yml:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
 encoders:
    Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

 providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: DeliveryAdminBundle:User
            property: username

 access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }

 firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        http_basic: ~
        provider: our_db_provider
```

User.php:

```
    <?php
namespace Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Delivery\AdminBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        if ($password) {
            $this->password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }
}
```

Login in database admin, password admin ($2a$08$jHZj/wJfcVKlIwr5AvR78euJxYK7Ku5kURNhNx.7.CSIJ3Pq6LEPC)

Help!)

Comment: DeliveryAdminBundle:User should be Delivery:AdminBundle:User

Comment: the problem is not solved

Comment: So some error returned or simply user is not authenticated? And how did you add user to the db?

Comment: User is not authenticated. I add manually in mysql

Comment: Can you post also code of your UserRepository?

Comment: <?php

namespace Delivery\AdminBundle\Repository;

/**
 * ClientRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class UserRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
}

Comment: Sorry but I meant whole source code. Please, edit your primary post and add source of your UserRepo...

Comment: I did not add anything to the UserRepo. My project is here https://github.com/zchipirov/delivery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your project, reviewed it and the problem is in few things:

1) You have defined your own login action in DeliveryAdminBundle -> SecurityController and  login form in corresponding view, so you have to configure `form_login` and ommit the `http_basic` in the security configuration to make it work.

In your App\Config\security.yml modify your firewalls -> main section to:

```
    pattern: ^/admin
    provider: our_db_provider
    anonymous: ~
    form_login:
      login_path: _security_login      #login route
      check_path: _security_check      #credentials check route
      failure_path: _security_login    #failed login route
      default_target_path: a_home      #successfull login route
    logout:
      path: _security_logout           #logout route
      target: f_home                   #route to redirect after logout
```

2) Because you have your security configuration under DeliveryAdminBundle, you have to modify App\Config\routing.yml to make login / logout routes work properly.

```
...
security_conf:
    resource: "@DeliveryAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.yml"
    prefix:   /admin
```

3) Because after step 2 your login route will point to ../admin/login, you have to make it accessible for non-autheticated users to let them log in. So in your App\Config\security.yml modify the access_control section to:

```
access_control:
  - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
  - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

4) Symfony's default names for login form fiedls are `_username` and `_password`, so modify your AdminBundle\Resources\views\Security\login.html.twig or change default formfield names in security.yml

Your encoders and providers configuration is perfecly fine as posted above, I was wrong with my first comment. I was confused by Delivery\AdminBundle namespace, but obviously you have bundle named DeliveryAdminBundle. It is a bit confusing, I would recommend you different naming strategy, but it's up to you.